# CHDataStructures.framework won't compile for iOS in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ios, compilation, chdatastructures

I downloaded CHDataStructures source code (r709), and tried to compile the iOS static library under xCode 4. It complained when compiling:

[image: Xcode build errors]

Can anyone give me some ideas how to compile it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the author of the framework, I was intrigued when Dave DeLong passed this link my way.

Turns out this isn't due to Xcode 4, it's due to changes in the iOS 4.3 SDK (and incidentally, the 10.7 SDK too). I was using the `OBJC_EXPORT` macro with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` (for which I defined a macro called `HIDDEN`). This wasn't a problem until 4.3/10.7 changed the definition of `OBJC_EXPORT` macro in `/usr/include/objc/objc-api.h`...

Previously, it was defined as `OBJC_EXTERN`, but now it's defined as `OBJC_EXTERN OBJC_VISIBLE`, which resolves to `OBJC_EXTERN __attribute__((visibility("default")))`. Thus, my declarations that used `HIDDEN OBJC_EXPORT` suddenly began resolving to:

```
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) OBJC_EXTERN __attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

Basically, the opposing visibility attributes were the cause of the errors. (Ready, fight!)

I've just tested and committed a fix which replaces `HIDDEN OBJC_EXPORT` with `HIDDEN`. Apparently those symbols didn't need to be declared as `extern` anyway, because it works without those macros.

So, the short answer to your question is: update to revision 710. ;-)

Comment: lol, thanks Quinn!!! Could  you please thanks me for testing it on iOS 4.3 and finding this issue?? lol

Comment: Indeed, many thanks! And if you find any further issues, feel free to email me.

Comment: Sure, just joking about the thanking. Thank you for developing this as it is very useful.

Comment: Quinn Taylor, I don't know how to contact you, it seems the downloading server is down? i can't access anything from it now. Any one can tell Quinn? his email is not working either.

Comment: You're correct that the server is down at the moment. I haven't worked out the cause yet, and it's in another state. :-/ My email is working fine, and you can find me at http://about.me/quinntaylor