# Adding External libraries on the Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am newbie of IOS developer. I am facing some problems that is I want to use external libraries on my xcode project. These are libraries that i need to use..[image: Libraries that I need to use]

I would like to know that How to add the external libraries on xcode. I put these libraries to the "include" folder under root folder of project. I facing this error.[image]

but library files are already exist in that folder. please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You followed these steps, yes? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the external library in your Build Phases further you can get easy help from this link or reply in comment 
[adding an external library to a project in XCode 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804149/adding-an-external-library-to-a-project-in-xcode-4-3)

Or go the project Choose Build Phases -> click the + sign to add one and then

[image]

Or in the above image click the button **Add Other** where you can tell the further path for the external library or click the link below for more help

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html

Comment: can i add those files' location in header search Path??

Comment: how???
this is original path....
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include

I would like to add  "include/ios_ffmpeg" folder. can you please guide me? thanks.