# Library Files missing in PJSIP project and how to link library files?

Tags: ios, sip, voip, pjsip, sip-server

I am using PjSIP for SIP calling. I have integrated PjSIP project as per the instruction on 
https://code.google.com/p/siphon/wiki/Compilation & [How To Build and Compile PJSIP for Xcode, Using sample code IPJSUA to test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848333/how-to-build-and-compile-pjsip-for-xcode-using-sample-code-ipjsua-to-test).

But when I opened the project, I found so many library with .a extensions are missing. Please find the screenshot for the same.

Is there anything which is missed by me or do I need to make changes or update anything ?

Also, let me know if any other library available for SIP calling.

[image]

- Thanks in Advance.
  Aakil.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iaz6ou84pnxla54/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-25%20at%2020.43.25.png?dl=0

Comment: This is the list with libs that your project need to run

Comment: maybe you added libs to project without selecting copy option and then removed them from the hdd ?

Comment: Actually I have downloaded the code from SVN & don't know from where to get the libraries.

Comment: Here is a Getting Started for iPhone http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

Answer (score 1):

It shows that library files are missing for compiling the project. **Either** you wrongly build your Project **or** you had changed the path of the library file into another place it doesn't know to access the library files.

**To Build Your PJSIP project,** Follow the below link to build for iphone:

Source: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

**To Add the missed library files into your project,** go to your project target and select the **Build phases** tab. Click **"+"** in Link Binary with Library option in that tab and add your missed library.

Follow below link:

Source: [adding an external library to a project in XCode 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804149/adding-an-external-library-to-a-project-in-xcode-4-3)