# CHDataStructures CHMutableDictionary HIDDEN void createCollectableCFMutableDictionary

Tags: xcode, macos, compilation, chdatastructures

Attempting to compile trunk@711 on OSX 10.8 with Xcode 4.5.2 getting compilation error.

CHMutableDictionary.m:54

```
Conflicting types for 'createCollectableCFMutableDictionary'
```

Looking at CHMutableDictionary.h:14

```
HIDDEN void createCollectableCFMutableDictionary(CFMutableDictionaryRef* dictionary, NSUInteger initialCapacity);
```

The Macro HIDDEN is discussed here: [CHDataStructures.framework won't compile for iOS in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418832/chdatastructures-framework-wont-compile-for-ios-in-xcode-4) but is about iOS.

I'm guessing a patch is needed to get this to compile on OSX as well?

Answer (score 0):

The `HIDDEN` attribute doesn't affect the compilation here, unlike the other question. It's complaining because the .m file has a `__strong` modifier on the first parameter, but it's missing from the .h file. You can resolve it by changing the declaration in the header to:

```
HIDDEN void createCollectableCFMutableDictionary(__strong CFMutableDictionaryRef* dictionary, NSUInteger initialCapacity);
```